# What is the meaning of below if condition?

Tags: qt, if-statement, networking, loopback, loopback-address

i cannot understand below if condition. if anyone know about it then please help me to understand it.

```
foreach(QNetworkInterface netInterface, QNetworkInterface::allInterfaces())
{
     if(!(netInterface.flags() & netInterface.IsLoopBack))
     {
          qDebug()<<netInterface.humanReadableName();
          qDebug()<<netInterface.hardwareAddress();
     }
}
```

Comment: What part of the condition are you having trouble with? The bitwise masking (with `&`)? The logical negation (with `!`)?

Comment: @Some programmer dude both &(and) and !(not). I can't understand the whole condition. What is the meaning of it ? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First lets start with the simple part: The logical negation operator `!`.

For any logical operation, the `!` reverses the status of that operation. So `!true` is `false`, and `!false` is `true`.

---

`netInterface.IsLoopBack` is the value of a single bit.

`netInterface.flags()` returns a set of bits.

`netInterface.flags() & netInterface.IsLoopBack` checks if the specific bit `netInterface.IsLoopBack` is in the set returned by `netInterface.flags()`.

---

Now putting it together, the result of `netInterface.flags() & netInterface.IsLoopBack` is an integer value. If the bit is in the set then it's non-zero.

In C++ all non-zero integer values is considered "true".

Applying the `!` operator on this value reverses the condition.

So the condition `!(netInterface.flags() & netInterface.IsLoopBack)` will be `true` is the bit is *not* in the set.

---

Lastly a bit of context: The loop iterates over all network interfaces on the local system.

If an interface is *not* a loopback interface (the address `127.0.0.1` is a loopback address) then the name and address of the interface is printed.

---

Addendum: All of this could have been figured out relatively easy by reading [some decent C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) for the operators. And reading the documentation for [`QNetworkInterface::flags()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkinterface.html#flags) and [`enum QNetworkInterface::InterfaceFlag`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkinterface.html#InterfaceFlag-enum).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I got it.